# angular date sort custom function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, date, jquery-ui-sortable

Im trying to do a custom sort for a table using angular.js. My angular module looks like this,

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])
angular.factory('sortable', ['$filter', '$rootScope', function($filter, $rootScope){

return function (scope, data, itemsPerPage, initSortingOrder) {

scope.sortingOrder = initSortingOrder;
scope.reverse = false;
scope.filteredItems = [];
scope.groupedItems = [];
scope.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
scope.pagedItems = [];
scope.currentPage = 1;
scope.items = data;
scope.maxSize = 5;

var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
      if (!needle) {
          return true;
      }
      return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  };


  // init the filtered items
  scope.search = function () {

      scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(scope.items, $rootScope.query);

      // take care of the sorting order
    if (scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
        scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')(scope.filteredItems, scope.sortingOrder, scope.reverse);
    }

      scope.currentPage = 1;

      // now group by pages
      scope.groupToPages();

      // reset the total items for the pagination buttons
      scope.totalItems = scope.filteredItems.length;
  };


  // calculate page in place
  scope.groupToPages = function () {
      scope.pagedItems = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
          if (i % scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
              scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / scope.itemsPerPage)] = [ scope.filteredItems[i] ];
          } else {
              scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / scope.itemsPerPage)].push(scope.filteredItems[i]);
          }
  }

  };


  scope.range = function (start, end) {
      var ret = [];
      if (!end) {
          end = start;
          start = 0;
      }
      for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
          ret.push(i);
      }
      return ret;
  };


  // functions have been described process the data for display
  scope.search();


  // change sorting order
  scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {
      if (scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
          scope.reverse = !scope.reverse;

      scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

      // call search again to make sort affect whole query
      scope.search();
  };

  scope.sort_by(initSortingOrder);
  scope.totalItems = scope.filteredItems.length;
  }

}])

  .controller('main', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', 'sortable', function($scope, $rootScope, sortable) {


$rootScope.query = '';

$scope.gridToggle = true;

$scope.onQueryChange = function(val){
   $rootScope.query = val;
   $scope.search();
};

var items = [
  { 'icon' : 'm-desktop', 'name' : 'Jerry\'s Blog',          'date' : '06/03/2016', 'user' : { 'name' : 'Jerry',   'color' : '#4677A7'} },
  { 'icon' : 'm-form',    'name' : 'Ape\'s Capture Form',    'date' : '01/06/2013', 'user' : { 'name' : 'Ape',     'color' : '#09ABC5'} },
  { 'icon' : 'm-phone',   'name' : 'Some Mobile Site',       'date' : '05/06/2015', 'user' : { 'name' : 'Someone', 'color' : '#456183'} },
  { 'icon' : 'm-bell',    'name' : 'Fish\'s Wordpress Site', 'date' : '04/06/2013', 'user' : { 'name' : 'Fish',    'color' : '#1CB7BB'} },
  { 'icon' : 'm-group',   'name' : 'Kitty Kat Kapture Form', 'date' : '05/06/2015', 'user' : { 'name' : 'Kitty',   'color' : '#1D9D9D'} }
];

sortable($scope, items, 6, 'updated_at');

  }]);
```

The sorting function works fine for strings. How do i go about converting a string date into a angular date object and then sort.

this is the entire html ,

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
  <header>

  <h1>Objects <span>( {{ items.length }} )</span></h1>
</header>
```

```
<div class="ctrls">

  <div class="filter">
    <span class="m m-search"></span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchies" ng-change="onQueryChange(searchies)" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter">
  </div>

  <div class="grid-toggle">
    <a ng-click="gridToggle = !gridToggle" ng-class="{ 'active' : gridToggle }">
      <span class="m m-squares"></span>
      <span class="m m-form"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="container">

  <ul class="grid" ng-class="{ 'grid-list' : gridToggle, 'grid-thumb' : !gridToggle }">
    <li class="grid-head">
      <ul>
        <li style="width:40%"><a ng-click="sort_by('name')">Name</a></li>
        <li style="width:30%"><a ng-click="sort_by('user.name')">User</a></li>
          <li style="width:15%"><a ng-click="sort_by('date')">Date</a></li>
        <li style="width:15%"></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="grid-body animate-repeat" ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage - 1] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse" ng-class="{'last':$last}">

      <ul>
        <li>

          <span class="grid-icon m" ng-class="item.icon"></span>
          <span class="grid-title"><a href="#">{{ item.name }}</a></span>
        </li>

        <li>
          <span class="grid-user">
            <span class="grid-usericon" ng-style="{ 'background' : item.user.color }">{{ item.user.name }}</span>
            <span class="grid-username">Updated by {{ item.user.name }}</span>
          </span>
        </li>

        <li>
          <span class="grid-date">{{ item.date }}</span>
        </li>

        <li>
          <span class="grid-options"><a href="#"><span class="m m-ellipsis"></span></a></span>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="clear-fix"></li>

    <li class="pagination">
      <pager total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pager>
      <p ng-if="itemsPerPage * currentPage < totalItems">
        Showing {{ itemsPerPage * currentPage - itemsPerPage + 1 }} - {{ itemsPerPage * currentPage }} of {{ totalItems }} total items
      </p>
      <p ng-if="itemsPerPage * currentPage >= totalItems">
        Showing {{ itemsPerPage * currentPage - itemsPerPage + 1 }} - {{ totalItems }} of {{ totalItems }} total items
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what an item in `pagedItems` looks like, but if they are strings which represent dates, you can convert them to `Date` objects by using `Date.parse(string)`.

See details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Once you have them as `Date` objects, you can sort them several ways. Here is an answer that will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124053/5780097

Comment: Please don't recommend using *Date.parse* (or the *Date* constructor to parse strings, they are equivalent). Built–in parsing is almost entirely implementation dependent and very unreliable across browsers. Date strings should be manually parsed, a library can help but usually isn't necessary.